# does induction work for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, induction, natural-numbers

im working on an simple question as:
Using induction, prove that for all complex numbers a and b and for all natural
numbers $m$ and $n$, we have $(ab)^n = a^n \cdot  b^n $and also $(a^m )^n = a^{mn}$ . If $a$ and $b$ are
nonzero, prove that these equations hold even if $m = 0$ or $n = 0$.

and for the first part, prove that for all complex numbers $a$ and $b$ and for all natural
numbers $m$ and $n$,  we have $(ab)^n = a^n \cdot  b^n$ and also $(a^m )^n = a^{mn}$ . i believe i have no problem to prove that for all natural numbers $m$ and $n$ by induction but im very not sure does the induction axiom work on complex number(ie: should i some how prove $M = \{a,b∈ C | ...\} = C$ or something else, like, can i just do $M =\{m,n ∈ N | \forall a,b ∈ C ....\} = N)$
and just to make the question a little more valuable, can we write induction for complex number? if so, how should we do it?

by the remind from @peek-a-boo , here is the solution i come up with:

Let $M =\{n ∈ N | \forall  (a,b) ∈ C , (ab)^n = a^n \cdot  b^n\}$

base case:

let $ n = 1, so (ab)^1 = ab $  which satisfy $M$

induction step:

Assume $ (ab)^n = a^n \cdot  b^n$

prove $(ab)^{n + 1} = a^{n + 1} \cdot  b^{n +1}$:

$ (ab)^{n+1} = (ab)^n  \cdot   ab $   and from assumption,
$(ab)^(n+1)=(ab)^n⋅ab=a^nb^n⋅ab$

which is the same as: $(ab)^n  \cdot   ab  = a^n  \cdot a  \cdot  b^n  \cdot  b $

Which shows  $(ab)^{n + 1} = a^{n + 1} \cdot  b^{n +1}$

Thus, we concludes that  $(ab)^n = a^n \cdot  b^n \implies  (ab)^{n + 1} = a^{n + 1} \cdot  b^{n +1}$

And by induction  now $M = N$

For $(a^m )^n = a^{mn}$ :
Let  $L =\{m,n ∈ N | \forall  a ∈ C , (a^m )^n = a^{mn}\}$
base case: Let $ m = 1$ and $ n = 1$  thus we have: $(a^1)^1 = a^1$
which satisfy the base case.
induction step:
recall that in this case, all natural number must be $ 1>=$, so if $ n> 1, n =1 + q , q  ∈ N$ . and if $ m> 1, m = 1 + p, p ∈ N$

Assume $(a^{1 + q})^{1 + p} = a^{(1 +q)(1 + p)}$,

prove $(a^{(1 + q) +1} )^{(1 + p)+1} = a^{((1 +q)+1)((1 + p)+1)}$

## i will jump this simple math since im very lazy, thank you :)

Thus we concludes that  $ (a^m )^n = a^{mn} \implies (a^{m +1} )^{n +1} = a^{(m+1)(n+1)}$

and from induction, we have$ L = N$  as we desire
Q.E.D

Given suggestion from @
CyclotomicField , i will try the second part again by using the first part:

For $(a^m )^n = a^{mn}$ :
Let  $L =\{m ∈ N | \forall  a ∈ C , \forall n ∈ N a^m )^n = a^{mn}\}$
(which n ∈ Nis given by the first part)
base case: Let $ m = 1$ thus we have: $(a^1)^n = a^n$
which satisfy the base case.
induction step: Assume $(a^m )^n = a^{mn}$ for $m$ is any given natural number, $U$.
prove $(a^(U+1) )^n = a^{(U+1)n}$:
$(a^(U+1) )^n = (a^(U)(a) )^n $
which is the same as $(a^(U)^n(a)^n$ #recall M
now from assumption, we have: $(a^(U)^n(a)^n =  a^{Un}(a)^n $
Thus $(a^(U)^n(a)^n =  a^{nU}(a)^n =  a^{n(U+1)} =  a^{(U+1)n}$
from above we concludes that :
$(a^m )^n = a^{mn} => (a^(m+1) )^n = a^{(m+1)n}$
which by induction, shows that $ L = N$ as we desire
Q.E.D

Also, recall what @
peek-a-boo
has just say that is :induction itself is a principle about natural numbers, not the "property" itself.
which my argue is that should induction work on any system that is close under successor or is that in this case all system that is close under successor was being defined as natural number?
if the first case holds, than can we not some how defined complex number be a system under successor and drive it though induction?
thank you so much for everyone that's been helping!

Comment: The principle of induction is a statement about natural numbers. Roughly speaking "if a property holds for $1$ and if the property holds for $n$ implies that it holds for $n+1$, then the property holds for all natural numbers". In your case the "property" is related to complex multiplication. But note that induction itself is a principle about natural numbers, not the "property" itself. So yes, you can use induction to prove the question. However, without you writing out your solution, we can't give you any feedback.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, thank you for answering the question! i will add my solution very soon

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematics in your posts.

Comment: @Lee Mosher thank you so much for the remind!! just know how to do it now

Comment: @peek-a-boo i have now upload my solution, please take a look

Comment: @Justpastby the first part is ok but you've overcomplicated the second part by not using the first part. You have also set up the induction incorrectly. The base case is fine but you are assuming what you want to prove. I recommend starting over and using the answer to the first part to make the second part induction over one variable instead of two. See if you can figure out what I mean.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, thank you, i will give a try later

Comment: "(ab)n+1=(ab)n⋅ab

and from assumption,

(ab)n⋅ab=an⋅a⋅bn⋅b"  That does not follow.  Your assumption is that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$.  So you have $(ab)^{n+1} = (ab)^n\cdot ab$ and so by your assumption you have that $(ab)^{n+1}=(ab)^n\cdot ab = a^nb^n\cdot ab$.  You do *not* have $(ab)^n\cdot ab = a^n\cdot a\cdot b^n\cdot b$ as you stated...  You have to *state* in your proof that $a^nb^n\cdot ab = a^n\cdot a\cdot b^n\cdot b$ (which you can claim by commutivity) and *THEN* you can say $a^n\cdot a\cdot b^n\cdot b=a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$ and be done.

Comment: @ fleablood oh, sorry, i thought i can jump such simple math that seems very clear to people that can read the text, i would change it right now.

Comment: @ peek-a-boo but follow  the way how induction works, should it works on all system that was close under successor?